# Get week day name from a given month, day and year individually in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, date

I am trying get a day name like friday, saturday, sunday, monday etc from a given date. I know there is a built in function which returns the day name for example:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'09/23/2013') as theDayName
```

this SQL query returns:

**'Monday'**

This is all OK. But I would like to pass `Month, Day and Year` individually.

I am using the builtin DATEPART function to retrieve month, day and year from a date so I can pass it to the DATENAME function:

```
SELECT DATEPART(m, GETDATE()) as theMonth  -- returns 11
SELECT DATEPART(d, GETDATE()) as theDay   -- returns 20
SELECT DATEPART(yy, GETDATE()) as theYear   -- returns 2013
```

Now that I have Month, Day, Year values individually, I pass it to my `DATENAME` to get the `Weekname` of the date I want:

```
--my SQL query to return dayName
SELECT (DATENAME(dw, DATEPART(m, GETDATE())/DATEPART(d, myDateCol1)/ DATEPART(yy, getdate())))  as myNameOfDay, FirstName, LastName FROM myTable
```

This returns an incorrect Day Name. I tried replace / with - so that in the DATENAME function my SQL query becomes:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'09/23/2013') 
--becomes
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'09-23-2013')
```

but it still returns incorrect dayName from my SQL query. Am I missing something here.

Please advise.

Comment: Please be aware of `select  @@DATEFIRST` which is set `SET DATEFIRST 7;`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to construct a date string.  You're using `/` or `-` operators which do MATH/numeric operations on the numeric return values of DATEPART.  Then `DATENAME` is taking that numeric value and interpreting it as a date.

You need to convert it to a string.  For example:

```
SELECT (
  DATENAME(dw, 
  CAST(DATEPART(m, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) 
  + '/' 
  + CAST(DATEPART(d, myDateCol1) AS VARCHAR) 
  + '/' 
  + CAST(DATEPART(yy, getdate()) AS VARCHAR))
  )
```

Comment: select DATENAME(DW,GETDATE()); This is enough to get day name.

Comment: That wasn't the issue or question, @AuthorPraWin

Comment: @EliGassert granted, but this is the top Stack Overflow result in Google for the term 'tsql day name' and this answer along with AuthorPraWin's useful addendum helped me immediately.

Answer (score 86):

Tested and works on SQL 2005 and 2008. Not sure if this works in 2012 and later.

The solution uses DATENAME instead of DATEPART

```
select datename(dw,getdate()) --Thursday
select datepart(dw,getdate()) --2
```

This is work in sql 2014 also.

Answer (score 8):

If you have SQL Server 2012:

If your date parts are integers then you can use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function.

```
SELECT DATENAME( dw, DATEFROMPARTS( @Year, @Month, @Day ) )
```

If your date parts are strings, then you can use the [`CONCAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) function.

```
SELECT DATENAME( dw, CONVERT( date, CONCAT( @Day, '/' , @Month, '/', @Year ), 103 ) )
```

Answer (score 8):

Try like this: `select DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),101))
```

Comment: Please provide some more details (e.g. a simple explanation of what you SQL script does) to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

select to_char(sysdate,'DAY') from dual;
It's  work try it

Comment: The database that OP is using is SQL Server. Your response is for Oracle. It will not work.

Comment: In the question, it's already mentioned that DB is SQL. You wrote it for Oracle

Answer (score -1):

I used

```
select
case
when (extract (weekday from DATE)=0) then 'Sunday'
```

and so on...

0 Sunday, 1 Monday...